# Как установить новую версию MySql через Docker?

Tags: mysql, debian, docker

Имеется Debian 8 с Mysql version 5.5.58 и на ней локально крутятся сайты.

Нужно поднять локально очередной сайт, но он крутится на продакшене на MySql ver 5.7.18-15.

Подскажите, как посредством Docker'a, соответственно не меняя версию текущей MySql, запустить новый сайт с БД другой версии, а то дамп не ставится из-за несовместимости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто поднять контейнер mysql:5.7:

```
docker run -d \
  --restart=always \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
  -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 \
  -v /var/dockerized-mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
  --name mysql-57 \
  mysql:5.7
```

Это создаст контейнер (грубо говоря, виртуальную машину), в которой будет крутиться один только MySQL. Пару слов о ключах:

- --restart=always говорит docker, что в случае падения контейнера его нужно будет переподнять
- -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root задает пароль для пользователя root внутри MySQL
- -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 пробрасывает порт 3306 контейнера как порт 127.0.0.1:3307 хост-машины, что позволит всем приложениям коннектиться к нему как к localhost:3307
- -v /var/dockerized-mysql:/var/lib/mysql смонтирует директорию /var/dockerized-mysql хост-машины как /var/lib/mysql внутри контейнера - благодаря этому вы будете знать, где живут ваши данные

После этого остается сконфигурировать приложение для доступа к MySQL, который теперь виден как сетевой сервис localhost:3307, логин и пароль для доступа - root и указанное значение MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:

```
etki@vortex ~ $ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -uroot -proot -e 'SELECT 1;'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра на работе попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Только вот никак не получается залить в эту базу дамп - http://i.piccy.info/i9/420312816c335182901b459574aee471/1519636873/122149/1224671/screen_docker.png

Comment: @Сергей это отдельная изолированная машина со своей файловой системой, в ней нет указанного файла. Используйте mysqldump.

Comment: Почему нет, я его залил, вот он, в home - http://i.piccy.info/i9/067dc15784130cdd0adbc9dbbeca8918/1519638943/23302/1224671/dump.png

Comment: @Сергей тогда стоит проверить, что там внутри за execute